# direct download from amazon s3 to client using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make my client side download a big file directly from amazon s3, without downloadin it through the server

using this function:

```
        $downloadUrl = $s3->getObjectUrl('dev-checkmate', '1.zip', '+5 minutes', array(
            'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename="test.zip"','Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
    ));
    return $downloadUrl;
```

gives me back a valid url that i can paste to the browser and the download will start, how can i make my web page to start that download without redirecting to the user to the url? (i dont want him to get a blank page, i want him to stay in my web page)

or maybe there is a differnet approach to make the user start the download from s3 directly?
the reason i dont want to use my server to do that is the files are pretty big, and i have slow bandwidth on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use javascript to open the download URL in a new window/tab. Usually if the browser detects the download the white page closes automatically.

Here's an example that fetches the download URL and then makes the redirect:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/download/test.zip', // change this to your real URL
    type: 'GET'
}).done(function(data){
    window.open(data);
});
```

Alternatively you could insert the download URLs when rendering the view so you don't need to make that ajax call.

Comment: good idea, thx. btw i tried to just putting the window open in my page, just to test if it will work, and my browser blocked it as a pop window. it has to be called by a user action (like click)

Comment: That's true. I assumed you would execute the download on a button click anyways so I didn't mention it ;)

Comment: when using this with ajax like u suggested the windows is still being blocked, even i a user click is waht called the ajax function

Comment: Hmm too bad. Then you will need to insert the right download URL when you render the view so you don't have to make the request. Do you need help with that?

Comment: i just solved it by opening the window before the ajax call

var newWindow = window.open();
and inside the ajax editing the location property 

newWindow.location = data['url'];

Comment: Nice! Haven't thought of that.

Comment: well. thers a differnet issue now, cause the browser doesnt recgonize a download starts when the blank page is opened, he doesnt close it.. its not so bad, but i would like to close it for a better user exprience, any thoughts? maybe even a differnet approch to start the download without the windows open?

Comment: Sorry no idea what you could do. Do some google searches and if you find nothing ask a new question on SO.